# Como colocar uma imagem no popup (na parte da barra de ferramentas (embaixo))?

Tags: javascript, imagem, popup

Como coloco uma imagem em uma popup usando javascript?

Ao abrir uma popup com `window.open`, ela abre sem imagem embaixo, apenas um desenho cinza. Como faço para colocar imagem? (embaixo, na barra de ferramentas.

O Google Chrome, por exemplo, tem a imagem dele, mas tem como por a mesma imagem dele ou uma personalizada ali, na popup?

Answer (score 1):

Na página que será carregada, inclua no `HTML`, na tag `head`:

- se for PNG:

  ```
  <link rel="icon" href="image.png" type="image/png" />
  ```
- se for ICO:

  ```
  <link rel="icon" href="image.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  ```

O `href` em cada exemplo acima, se refere ao caminho de onde será carregado o arquivo da imagem.